# How do I get inside the treehouse in the Haunted Tower?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

I beat the boss of the Haunted Tower, but it wouldn't let me into the treehouse itself. Instead Luigi just picked up the gem and the way to the boss are is blocked by a spider web in the Hostile Intrusion. Is there any way into the treehouse?

Comment: Was there anything that indicated to you that you could go inside the house? I just did that part and didn't notice anything.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat All doors prior to this one can be interacted with in some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple answer: You can't. The stairs are the boss ghost.

Answer (score -1):

You may need the spike ball that appears when the possessor is gone. This automatically gets removed in a cutscene. You may have to hack to get it back.